# Intent in Xamarin not passing correct value

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-intent, xamarin

I'm currently working on a small game for android using Xamarin in Visual Studio, I have activities for the gameplay, and the game over screen. On the game over screen I want the users score to be displayed, which I get from an intent. This works perfectly the first time, but if the user chooses to restart the game, no matter what they score, the game over screen defaults their score to zero. How can I fix this so that the correct score is displayed everytime? Also I'm still fairly new to this so any help at all would be great!

**Code in Game class the calls the game over screen**

```
this.intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(GameOverAct));
                this.intent.PutExtra("ThePoint", buttons.score);
                this.intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

**Game Over Activity**

```
public class GameOverAct : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.AndroidGameActivity
{
    TextView score;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        score = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.scoretext);
        score.Text = "Score: " + getGameScore();
        removescore();

        Button restart = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.restart);
        restart.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
        Button mm = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.mainmenu);
        mm.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var intent3 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainMenuAct));
            StartActivity(intent3);
        };
    }
    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        score = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.scoretext);
        score.Text = "Score: " + getGameScore();
        removescore();
        Button restart = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.restart);
        restart.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
        Button mm = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.mainmenu);
        mm.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var intent3 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainMenuAct));
            StartActivity(intent3);
        };
    }
    public int getGameScore()
    {
        int a = Intent.GetIntExtra("ThePoint", 0);
        return a;
    }
    public void removescore()
    {
        Intent.RemoveExtra("ThePoint");
    }
 }
```

**Activity that runs the Game class**

```
public class Activity1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.AndroidGameActivity
{
    Game1 g;

    //When the Game is played for the first time after launching the app, this method is called
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        //Gets a Game1 object, which is the class that builds the game
        this.g = new Game1();
        //sets it to view
        SetContentView((View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));
        g.Run();


    }
    //If the player chooses to restart, this method is called
    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
        this.g = new Game1();
        SetContentView((View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));
        g.Run();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `buttons.score` a int type value? I cannot reproduce your issue based on your posted code.

Comment: Yes, it is an int

Comment: Can your please provide a minimal reproduceable demo?

Comment: Nevermind I solved it, I just created a new project and copied my code over to that and it worked